# Angular 1.5 to use transclude or not to use transclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A question regarding transclude within an angular 1.5.8 component, and it's uses.

Here is an example of some code;

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

function AccordionController () {
  var self = this;
  // add panel
  self.addPanel = function(panel) {
    // code to add panel
  }

  self.selectPanel = function() {
    //code to select panel
  }
}

// register the accordion component
app.component('accordion', {
  template: '<!---accordion-template-->',
  controller: AccordionController
}

function AccordionPanelController () {
  // use parents methods here
  var self = this;

  // add panel
  self.parent.addPanel(self);

  // select panel
  self.parent.selectPanel(self);
}

// register the accordion-panel component
app.component('accordionPanel', {
  // require the parent component
  // In this case parent is an instance of accordion component
  require: {
    'parent': '^accordion',
  template: '<!---accrodion-panel-template-->',
  controller: AccordionController
}
```

My question is would it be better to nest all the according panels within the parent using transclude or alternatively pass in a data array to the parent which this loops out the required number of panels based on the array passed inside using a binding.

Thanks

// added

Many thanks for your reply, an example I have of transclude possibly being necessary is in the following bit of code

```
<modal modal-id="editCompany" title="Edit Company"> <company-form company="$ctrl.company"></company-form> </modal>
```

Here we have a modal component which may have a variety of other components used within it, on the example above I am adding the company form, but this could we be an contact form. is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with angular pretty extensively. Two enterprise tools managing and displaying large amounts of data, dozens of interactive widget modules, all that.

Never, once, have I had anything to do with transclude. At work we are explicitly told not to use it (link functions too). I thought this was a good thing, and the way Angular 2 turned out it seemed that thinking wasn't totally without reason.

I would go with the iteration to lay out the required number of items. At work this wouldn't be a choice because transclude wouldn't be an option.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, an example I have of transclude possibly being necessary is in the following bit of code

        `<modal modal-id="editCompany" title="Edit Company">
            <company-form company="$ctrl.company"></company-form>
        </modal>`


Here we have a modal component which may have a variety of other components used within it, on the example above I am adding the company form, but this could we be an contact form. is there an alternative way?

Comment: Absolutely. Use a service. One app I wrote requires popups with nested components (I actually dislike that overall UX, but sometimes it makes sense). I just created something called a PopupService which gets injected into the popup directive controller. 

I generally think that treating your data as a completely separate layer of your app, and using services to hold and provide that data, as opposed to sending events up and down the view hierarchy and so on, is cleaner. I never sweat where in the hierarchy a component is, nor should you; if you rework the UI markup, you'll break your code.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with using `transclude` in a component architecture is that it visually breaks the idea of single responsibility and messes with the architecture.

```
<html>
  <navigation></navigation>
  <accordion>
    <accordion-panel></accordion-panel>
  </accordion>
  <footer></footer>
</html>
```

In this example you know your page has a navigation menu, an accordion and a footer. But at the index level (or root component) you don't want to know / see what the accordion contains.

So the accordion-panel component should only appear in its direct parent component.

As for your other question, through the use of `require` or  `attributes` you pass an array of panels that you iterate using ng-repeat inside the accordion component.

```
app.component('accordion', {
  template: `<accordion-panel ng-repeat="..."></accordion-panel>`,
  controller: AccordionController
}
```